# How to build a throttled ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Here's my problem:

1. I have a long-running calculation (let's call it the "task") performed after receiving an event.
2. The events tell me that there is more data to process.  The event includes an index of where I can now safely process data for the task.
3. When I get a new event, I have more data that I will need to process eventually.
4. When I get a new event, I don't want to cancel the existing task but let it finish and then start the next task.
5. If I get several events during a task, the next task should only process the most recent event and discard all previous events.
6. I only have enough resources to process one task at a time.

Is there a modified version of the `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` I can use to implement the above conditions?  Can I do something elegant with a BlockingQueue or AtomicReferences?  Is there a simple way to do what I am describing above?

Comment: So I don't understand what is different about this than a simple producer/consumer problem where there is only 1 consumer and the producers are putting the events into a queue that only fits one element.  Am I missing something in your question?

Comment: You are pretty close to correct.  The main issue lies in to the one element on the queue.  It has to be the most recent element not the earliest.  So you could almost consider it a one element stack.  Do you know of a solution in Java that could do this in a simple, elegant manner?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Java ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor which is an extension of ThreadPoolExecutor. You can limit the thread pool size to 1 to make sure only one task is picked from the queue. The only problem for you is that ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor internally uses an implementation of DelayQueue which is an unbounded queue but you want only the last task/event to be picked.

You may have to extend ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor class and use a different queue then the DelayedWorkQueue that is bound to the current ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor implementation. Note that DelayedWorkQueue is only a BlockingQueue implementation that is using a DelayQueue behind the scene. Override all the schedule* methods and implement your own bounding of tasks.

Answer (score 0):

One may like to extend to extend ThreadPoolExecutor to achieve the desired result for e.g.

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(min, max, keepAliveTime,
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()) {

      @Override
      protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
        while (isThrottle()) {
          try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(timeout);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      private double isThrottle() {
        // TODO: 
      }
    };
```